# Interface Builder - Tricky Autolayout Situation

Tags: interface-builder

Here's my current layout:

[image]

The layout above works fine pre iphone6 but once the view is set to iphone6+ then you get:

[image]

FYI Those images look like the same size because of how they are displayed in sof. Click the image itself and you'll the actual size/scale of the image.

I get why that this is happening because my text areas are staying in the same place on the image while the image has actually changed in size (respecting aspect ratio). So my question is, how do I get these text fields to move in respect to the image behind it getting larger while still keeping their relative position & size against the image?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the vertical text Days, Hrs, and Mins the image and use that as the background image.

Then make 3 separate images one for each Days, Hrs, and Mins.

From there use auto layout to do the following:

[Days image][00]  [Hrs image][01]   [Mins image][02]